# How to use coursier with a Proxy

Tags: scala, coursier

Coursier is a Scala Download Tool. The instructions say to use `-Dhttps.proxyHost`, but it did not work for me:

```
./coursier bootstrap --java-opt -Xss4m --java-opt -Xms100m --java-opt -Dmetals.client=emacs   -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 org.scalameta:metals_2.12:0.7.6 -r bintray:scalacenter/releases -r sonatype:snapshots -o /usr/local/bin/metals-emacs -f
```

How do you use coursier (on Ubuntu) with a Proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `-J-Dhttps.proxyHost` and `-J-Dhttps.proxyPort` flags:

```
./coursier bootstrap --java-opt -Xss4m --java-opt -Xms100m --java-opt -Dmetals.client=emacs -J-Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -J-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 org.scalameta:metals_2.12:0.7.6   -r bintray:scalacenter/releases -r sonatype:snapshots -o /usr/local/bin/metals-emacs -f
```